# Raspberry Pi Rapid Development Shield-Atlas Scientific-Reading Two(2) Sensors at the Same Time

Tags: sensor, setup

Has anyone tried to use Atlas Scientific Raspberry Pi Rapid Development Shield:

[image]

Can this shield run two(2) sensors at the same time(i.e., Thermometer probe and pH probe) and read both inputs?

here is the link for the product:

http://www.atlas-scientific.com/product_pages/components/raspberry_pi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is not.  Serial ports usually only allow for one connection through a given port, and the datasheet seems to suggest that it's only meant for one device to be plugged in at a given time (notice the datasheet consistently says 'or').

If you want a definitive answer, I'd suggest contacting the company directly since their documentation is rather sparse.

Comment: Yes I did sent an email to the manufacturer, he actually said a big YES. I wonder it really does work. I guess I'll just google it or something. Or maybe somebody here already used it. I'll wait for more answers. Thank you for your answer.